# rtree is indexable assertion

Tags: c++, boost, r-tree, boost-geometry

Here is the piece of my code. I am trying to create a rtree tree for the vertex class objects **RTreeVertex**.

```
class Entity {

public:
  int num;
public:
  Entity(int nr): num(nr){ }
  virtual ~Entity(){}
   bool operator==(const Entity& b)
   {
     return num == b.num;
   } 
};


class Vertex : public Entity {

public : 
  struct Coord{
  double X, Y, Z;  
  }Pos;

  Vertex(int num=0, double X=0., double Y=0., double Z=0.): Entity (num)
  {
    Pos.X = X;
    Pos.Y = Y;
    Pos.Z = Z;
  }
};
```

here is how I declare the rtree:

```
#include <boost/geometry/index/rtree.hpp>
namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;
bgi::rtree< Vertex, bgi::linear<32> > RTreeVertex;
```

but I get an error saying that vertec is not Indexable.

and one more *general* question: Is it a good idea to use rtree for storing data related to a mesh?

Answer (score 2):

You have to register your point class with boost geometry. It creates a slew of traits for your class. I tested this, it works.

```
    class Vertex : public Entity {

    public : 
            double X, Y, Z;  

        Vertex(int num=0, double x=0., double y=0., double z=0.): Entity (num)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
            Z = z;
        }
    };

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_3D( Vertex, double, bg::cs::cartesian, X, X, X );
#include <boost/geometry/index/rtree.hpp>
namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;
bgi::rtree< Vertex, bgi::linear<32> > RTreeVertex;
```

I could not get it to work with X,Y,Z in a structure with Pos::X..., there may be a way. You could join the geometry group on boost.org. They are the geometry experts.

Addendum:
I was curious, so I looked at how REGISTER.. works. With:

```
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_3D( Vertex, double, bg::cs::cartesian, Pos.X, Pos.Y, Pos.Z );
```

You can use your structure for your x,y,z.

And namespace bg = boost::geometry;

is the name space I used above

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I have a Line and surface classes which are also derived from Entity class. How would I register them into boost geometry as well?

Comment: look in: boost\geometry\geometries\register  all the macros for registering classes are in there and [geometry pdf](https://meetingcpp.com/tl_files/mcpp/slides/12/meetingcpp_boost_geometry_2012.pdf) if you want to roll your own traits.